# Dump email in custom object

Tags: emailtosalesforce, email2case

I have looked through the site and Google and have come up empty - with such vague terms to search with I am terribly sorry if this has been asked 100 times - if so please point my in the right direction and I'll be on my way...

I would like the ability to use something similar to Email to Salesforce where I can send an email to a specific email address and the email literally gets dumped in a custom object. For instance the custom object would have a to, from, body, cc and bcc fields and I would just dump the body of the email into these fields.

My plan is to then handle these fields using mapping based on common email bodies/content and create rich Leads (better quality than just dumping straight into a lead/case).

Is this possible? If anyone has an example apex class I would rather use that than implement another 3rd party app from the app exchange that i will end up supporting...

But honestly anything will do to get me started :)

**=============== EDIT ===============**

For anyone who comes across this post, a good place to start would be to read about Email Services:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_email_services_editing.htm

Comment: You should look for email services. This does exactly what you're looking for. You can check out more details about it here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to this:

**Solution 1**

Currently when emails are received in Salesforce (using email to case for example) - you have flexibility to assign to queues or users based on some rules, etc. - All emails are created in a record called **EmailMessage**. This contains all the usual fields you would expect (from, to, headers, dates, message body, etc.). It is possible that you create a trigger on the creation of a new case, take the info from EmailMessage record and map to whatever custom object you want. Of course this assumes that all the info you need is derived from **EmailMessage**.

---

**Solution 2**

The only other way of doing this is to override the standard email Handler. You must create an Apex class that implements the **InboundEmailHandler**

```
global class myCustomEmailHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    //your code to map to custom object
}
```

You need to be a bit careful here because you are literally overriding the standard Salesforce email handler.
I found this to be a very good article on how to override the standard email handler:
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/12/writing-an-inbound-email-service-for-salesforce-com/

Comment: Solution 2 is exactly what I am after - created an email service to create a dump of the email in a record. Then I will write a trigger to attempt to process the dump based on common body formatting. Thank you!